# how to put a sequence number for an xml element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have several elements with the same name (for example, "risks"), but using xslt I need to put an ordinal number for the elements (for example, risks_1, risks_2). Here is an example of the input xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <response>
        <score>0.8</score>
        <risks>5001</risks>
        <risks>1006</risks>
        <risks>1045</risks>
        ......
        <risks>1456</risks>
        <version>SCO</version>
     </response>
```

Expected xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>
    <response>
      <score>0.8\</score>
      <risks_1>5001</risks_1>
      <risks_2>1006</risks_2>
      <risks_3>1045</risks_3>
      .....
      <risks_n>1456</risks_n>
      <version>SCO</version>
    </response>
```

I am new to xslt, my attempt is unsuccessful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="/response">
        <xsl:element name="SCO">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'risks'"> 
            <xsl:element name="{concat({local-name()},format-number(count(preceding::risks)+1,'0')}"></xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>     
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do that? It doesn't seem like a great idea to me. What is the reason for the requirement, if you don't mind my asking? Maybe there's some other way to achieve whatever benefit you are hoping to get out of it.

Comment: I completely agree with you) But this is exactly the requirement

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Hint: you can use the `position()` function.

Comment: attached my attempt

Comment: A better approach would be to add an attribute to the  `<risks>` element. Something like  `<risks seq="1">`, `<risks seq="2">`, etc.

Comment: unfortunately the condition is to change the name of the element itself

Comment: I'm with Conal Tuohy, putting ordinal numbers in element names is NOT a good idea, because it makes it really hard to parse the document with XSL / XPath that would typically look for "//element". I agree with Yitzhak Khabinsky's attribute suggestion as a comprimise.

Comment: Hi Serg! What is the reason for the requirement to rename these elements? Can that reason be addressed in some other way? Because this is really not good practice. Do you have some other existing system that requires elements named this way? If so, can you fix that system instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/response">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="score"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="risks">
            <xsl:element name="risks_{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:copy-of select="version"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```